# Kendo upload not working in IE 8

Tags: servlets, internet-explorer-8, kendo-ui

## Context

I am using asynchronous [Kendo UI Upload](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/web/upload/overview) ([docs](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/upload)) in my application with HTML frontend and Java servlet at server side. When servlet returns nothing in response, it’s working perfectly. Uploading triggers progress change to “Done” on success, `complete` callback method is called.

## Problem

I need to return some data such as `GUID="SDR2334"` from the server on successful upload. When I send response from the servlet, Kendo UI Upload control does not work/render as expected/as [shown in Kendo demo site](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/upload/async.html) at all.

1. progress not getting changed to “Done” when uploading
2. `complete` method not being called

## Attempted solution

I tried to add GUID with response header instead of response body. Still it’s not working.

### Code I used

```html
<form method="post" action="submit" style="width:45%">
    <div class="demo-section">
        <input name="files" id="files" type="file" />
    </div>
</form>
```

```js
$("#files").kendoUpload({
    async: {
        saveUrl: "http:111.11.11.111/fileupload",
        autoUpload: false
    },
    multiple: false,
    showFileList: true,
    upload: function (e) {
        e.data = { sessionid: CurrentSession.sessionId };
    },
    complete: function (e) {
        alert(e.data);
        $(".k-widget.k-upload").find("ul").remove();
    }
});
```

### Request header

```
Key             Value
Request         POST /services/fileUploadWithoutResponse HTTP/1.1
Accept          application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*
Referer         http://111.11.11.11:8090/WebClient/
Accept-Language en-US
User-Agent      Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Content-Type    multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7de38b1219073a
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Host            172.16.17.100:8090
Content-Length  114034
DNT             1
Connection      Keep-Alive
Cache-Control   no-cache
```

### Response header

```
Key             Value
Response        HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server          Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Powered-By    Servlet 2.5; JBoss-5.0/JBossWeb-2.1
Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
guId            f6ac7203-5bd6-433b-a632-548ca5b048cf
Content-Type    application/json;charset=utf-8
Content-Length  0
Date            Fri, 03 Jan 2014 13:00:19 GMT
```

Notice the `guId` header here.

Comment: Maybe a related one: http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/upload/complete-error-callbacks-are-not-firing.aspx

Comment: Thanks for reply.but link is not helpfull for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it by setting the response content-type to text/plain.

Also I realized I need [`success` event](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/upload#events-success) instead of [`complete` event](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/upload#events-complete) to get the contents of response body (`e.response`).

Comment: Would it be possible to show full updated working code please, i.e. where did you set the response content-type to text/plain?

Comment: I have set response content-type in my service.